# vb.net: DES decryption error while using memory stream

Tags: vb.net, des

This is my code for des decryption. I dont know why it showing error on CopyTo function.

```
Private Function Unsecure(ByVal sInput As Byte(), ByVal sKey As String)
  'Define the service provider
  Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

  DES.Key() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)
  DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

  'Define the crypto transformer
  Dim cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform

  cryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor 

  Dim ms As New MemoryStream(sInput)   
  Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read)    
  Dim ms1 As New MemoryStream()

  cryptostream.CopyTo(ms1) '// <- **Error: CopyTo is not a member of System.Security.Cryptography.Cryptostream**

  Return ms1.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: [CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx) was added in .Net 4.0.  Maybe you're compiling against 3.5 or lower?

Comment: Sir, u r right i changed dat to .net 4.0 framework, no error.. thank you soo much..

Comment: But now ders another showing in the same place. err: Length of data to decrypt is invalid.. :(